# Display Issue on IOS device when build from unity to xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I was having problem when building my project for IPhone 6+. So I made a simple scene in unity which has a simple camera and a ball gameobject and exported it to XCode. but when I run it on ios device its upper half screen has some weird display issue. can somebody help?

reference images

Problem: https://www.gmonks.com/help/1.jpg

Camera setting: https://www.gmonks.com/help/2.png

Comment: Could you provide more information? Maybe you sample project?

Comment: https://www.gmonks.com/help/3DBallJump.zip

Comment: Since it is a very large project I have stripped down the project file it contains only simple scene with 3 sphere and a camera. project is building properly on android and IOS both but now sphere is not even visible on ios device. If somebody can connect to me on skype I can show him the project file. Here is link of project file.  https://www.gmonks.com/help/3DBallJump.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. I have created a completely new project and imported all assets one by one, now project is building properly on IPhone. Although this issue still exist in the old project, creating new project seems the easiest fix to me. Few thing are different from my old project and new project, which are the setting of **quality in project setting** and **Lighting in windows**. I think I have messed up some value in there. If anyone wants to take look then please download the project file and if possible can explain why did this happened. anyways thank for your support.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the time to look at it, yet. But nice to hear, that you managed to solve it (event though its more a workaround solution). Why don't you just compare those differences to check what caused the problem? I would have to do the same.